# Can I pass variables to cluster.fork in node.js?

Tags: node.js

So right now I have a bunch of chat bots, and I use a wrapper to start each one as a child process. It forks a config file. However, since each bot has a webiste, it means that express has to run on an unique port for each bot. I would like to have all the bots run the webserver on the same port. Which led me to look at cluster rather than child.

I am currently using `child.fork(config.js);` to spawn the bots, and it's working as well as can be expected.

But Is there any way to pass the config variables to `cluster.fork` so each worker can connect to its own chat room with its own login credentials?

And if it is possible, is there a way to kill/restart a worker like a child process?

Comment: I've tried a few different layouts, but I can't get the wrapper (master) to start a server and then each child to define routes on the same port. At a loss.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

You could augment your `process.env`, and then use that in the forked process.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var child = require('child_process');
var env = _.clone(process.env);

env.BOT_ID = 'dalton';
child.fork('./config.js', { env: env });
```

I'd suggest you keep the smallest amount of info in `env`, and then just use that to grab the configuration from a JSON file, or something.

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing. I was looking for passing info to `cluster.fork`. Does passing the env make it so where the child processes share ports?

Comment: If you need a unique port for each child, then `cluster` is not what you're looking for. Refer to the docs: _"The cluster module allows you to easily create child processes that all share server ports."_

Comment: I don't unique ports. I need them all on the same port. Sorry if I didn't make that very clear. Because right now, each bot's website is on a different port, which is tacky. bots.example.com:3001/bot doesn't have the ring to it it should.

Comment: OP sounded like you wanted that behavior _"However, each bot does some website stuff, which means that express has to run on an unique port for each bot."_. If you don't, then yeah, `cluster.fork` passing an `env` should do it.

Comment: Okay, but my code is compartmentalized. So it loads files based on the config. And if cluster is just a clone of the current app, then that would break, no?

Comment: It's not just a clone, it's a different process, which means you can tweak them by passing environment variables and using them to differentiate your workers. Similarly you could use the cluster API to figure out [what kind of worker](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_class_worker) you are.

Comment: I'm researching now. Trying to figure out how to convert my wrapper so that it spawns a cluster rather than child elements.

Comment: "*I'd suggest you keep the smallest amount of info in env*", what is the reason for that?